# change returnurl of ccavenue in magento 2.2.11

Tags: magento, magento2, ccavenue

i have installed ccavenue extension in magento-2.2.11 and i have added all the required details in that. but when i make payment of any order. then magento redirects it to 'ccavenuepay/ccavenuepay/returnurl/' which is showing 'there has been error processing your request'.

i also tried to redirect to success page as given below:

```
 public function getCcavneueReturnUrl(array $params) {
    $this->logger->info("getCcavneueReturnUrl");
    //return $this->_getUrl('ccavenuepay/ccavenuepay/returnurl', $params);
    return $this->_getUrl('checkout/onepage/success/', $params);
 }
```

but it redirects to cart page after payment.

What should i do to redirect it to success page?

TIA

i am getting given json in my log. which is showing please provide payment for the order:

```
{"0":"Please provide payment for the order.","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(&Magento\\Payment\\Observer\\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver#000000007f15a7e9000000000be88ea3#, &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007f15a781000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Payment\\...', 'name' => 'payment_sales_or...'), &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007f15a781000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php:66]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('sales_order_save...', array('data_object' => &Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#, 'order' => &Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#)) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch('sales_order_save...', array('data_object' => &Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#, 'order' => &Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Model\/AbstractModel.php:694]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->beforeSave() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Sales\/Model\/Order\/Interceptor.php:5068]\n#6 Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor->beforeSave() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Db\/AbstractDb.php:406]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Db\\AbstractDb->save(&Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-sales\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Order.php:178]\n#8 Magento\\Sales\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Order->save(&Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Sales\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Order\/Interceptor.php:37]\n#9 Magento\\Sales\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Order\\Interceptor->save(&Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor#000000007f15a7f0000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Model\/AbstractModel.php:647]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->save() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Sales\/Model\/Order\/Interceptor.php:5029]\n#11 Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor->save() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Ccavenuepay\/Controller\/Ccavenuepay\/ReturnUrl.php:121]\n#12 Magento\\Ccavenuepay\\Controller\\Ccavenuepay\\ReturnUrl->execute() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Ccavenuepay\/Controller\/Ccavenuepay\/ReturnUrl\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#13 Magento\\Ccavenuepay\\Controller\\Ccavenuepay\\ReturnUrl\\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:107]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#15 Magento\\Ccavenuepay\\Controller\\Ccavenuepay\\ReturnUrl\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#16 Magento\\Ccavenuepay\\Controller\\Ccavenuepay\\ReturnUrl\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#17 Magento\\Ccavenuepay\\Controller\\Ccavenuepay\\ReturnUrl\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Ccavenuepay\/Controller\/Ccavenuepay\/ReturnUrl\/Interceptor.php:52]\n#18 Magento\\Ccavenuepay\\Controller\\Ccavenuepay\\ReturnUrl\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:55]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#22 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#000000007f15a210000000000be88ea3#, &Closure#000000007f15a204000000000be88ea3#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#24 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#000000007f15a210000000000be88ea3#, &Closure#000000007f15a204000000000be88ea3#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007f15a3e1000000000be88ea3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:257]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000007f15a396000000000be88ea3#) called at [index.php:44]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/default\/ccavenuepay\/ccavenuepay\/returnurl\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect back to `ccavenuepay/ccavenuepay/returnurl`, it's showing an error mean the coding process on the return URL is having problems, you should check `var/log/exception.log` and revise the problems first.

Comment: i have updated my log in my question. please have a look into that and tell me the solution if you know as i am using test details with test gateway.

Comment: Following the log you have provided, I saw it thrown exception that Order doesn't have Payment yet. You should take a look at the payment gateway, events of payment method, and JS for rendering the payment